# How to compute the limit of an infinitely nested function in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

Take the function:

f(x) = sqrt( ... sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(x)-1)+1)-1)+1)-1 ...) +1

I want to find the limit of the function for a given value of x as the number of iterations tends towards infinity.

How? I am using Wolfram Alpha, could not get the "Nest" functions to work (and unsure if they'd help anyway).

Comment: Can you use mathematica? Bacause questions about WA syntax are off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest) as follows:

```
Nest[Sqrt[Sqrt[#] - 1] + 1&, 2., 100]
```

> 1.4534

Or, you can use the usual trick for these kinds of things:

```
NSolve[r == Sqrt[Sqrt[r] - 1] + 1, r]
```

> {{r -> 1.4534}, {r -> 1.}}

Comment: Thanks. Nest function sadly doesn't work on WA but I thought it was a general Wolfram stack exchange. Your answer is correct for Mathematica so I'll check it. (I ended up just doing it manually on my TI 89 lol).

Comment: @CommaToast The following WA [input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Nest%5BSqrt%5BSqrt%5B%23%5D-1%5D%2B1%26,+2,+10%5D) works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 fixed points. You can solve and illustrate,e.g.:

```
Solve[f[x] == x, x]
f[x_] := Sqrt[x - 1] + 1
nf[x_, n_] := Nest[f, x, n]
Manipulate[
 DiscretePlot[nf[x0, j], {j, 1, 10, 1}, GridLines -> {None, {2}}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 5}], {x0, 1.1, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]